# App Engine stops responding to Firebase Database changes after a while

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app which uses Firebase as a datastore. I've developed Google App Engine backend in Java, that verifies the data from my mobile users.

However, after a while the backend stops reacting to changes in Firebase. I'm using a ChildEventListener in the backend to listen for changes in nodes.

Does anybody have a good idea as to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard environment closes all network connections after a while.
I moved the backend to the flexible environment by adding `<vm>true</vm>` to the root section of appengine-web.xml. That fixed the issue.